# Get a random image from tumblr

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr

How can I get and then display a random image from a post from a specific tumblr with javascript?

I want it to be simple, something like when a button is pushed display a the random image.

I'm just going to use foodgif.tumblr.com as an example.  So far I know you can get a random post just by including /random onto the end of the url.  (so http://foodgif.tumblr.com/random will grab a random url that could be used to grab the image from)

I also found [tumblrbot](https://github.com/iangreenleaf/node-tumblrbot), which is a Hubot-compatible Tumblr API wrapper for Node.js, and has code like the following:

```
tumblr = require('tumblrbot')

tumblr.photo("foodgif.tumblr.com").random (post) ->
          console.log post.photos[0].original_size.url
```

but all their code/examples seems to be in coffee script, and I'm already new to html/javascript/jquery.  Is there code usable in normal javascript?

I could also just use the actual tumblr API, but other methods seems simpler and promising, so I'd rather that be a last resort.  Anyway I feel like I've got the means capable to do it, I just don't really know exactly how.  Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote example that get photos from foodgif blog via JS. Link is below.

[Tumblr API - Get Photos via JS (JS Bin)](http://jsbin.com/efaciz/4/)

If you want to use this code, you must change api key.

Comment: Thanks for the start, now I need to work on learning ajax as well.  It looks like tumblrbot won't work out because require() doesn't work browser side.

Answer (score 1):

CoffeeScript compiles into Javascript, so if you install CoffeeScript and compile the .coffee files, you will get .js output which you would be more familiar with.

http://coffeescript.org/ the homepage has the overview for the installation and compilation process.